# Deserialize XML into object array

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

This is a relatively common problem (judging from the number of questions on it) but the problem I'm having seems to be different (none of the other solutions seems to apply).

I'm trying to add XML serialization to a class that is already being serialized "over the wire".  My class structure is like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct G
{
    public PN P;
    public byte FillerByte;
    public PRD PDef;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PRD
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool PD1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool PD2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = CPD.NameChars)]
    public String PN;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = CPF.Bytes)]
    public byte[] AF;
    public byte PFI;
    public PSB PV;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = NumPLD)]
    public PLD[] PLD;
    // NumPLD = 4
    // Yes, both the class and this member variable are named PLD
}
```

When I serialize this, the XML looks good:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<G xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<P>_2</P>
<FillerByte>0</FillerByte>
<PDef>
   <PD1>false</PD1>
   <PD2>false</PD2>
   <PN>P A</PN>
   <PFI>0</PFI>
   <PV>None</PV>  
   <PLD>
      <PLD>
         <..contents of first PLD>
      </PLD>
      <PLD>
         <..contents of second PLD>
      </PLD>
      <PLD>
         <..contents of third PLD>
      </PLD>
      <PLD>
         <..contents of fourth PLD>
      </PLD>
   </PLD>
</PDef>
</G>
```

When I deserialize this, everything shows up fine except the PLD array.  I've got handlers catching all the various errors:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(G));
x.UnknownAttribute += new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeEventHandler(UnknownAttribute);
x.UnknownElement += new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementEventHandler(UnknownElement);
x.UnknownNode += new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlNodeEventHandler(UnknownNode);
x.UnreferencedObject += new System.Xml.Serialization.UnreferencedObjectEventHandler(UnreferencedObject);
```

None of those events ever get triggered.

How do I convince the XML parser to deserialize my array of PLD objects?  Am I having problems because the class name and the member variable name are the same ("PLD")?

---

I've created a simpler example that shows the problem, it seems to be related to having nested structs:

```
public struct Fred
{
    public string Name;
}

public struct Middle
{
    public Fred[] Freds;
}

public struct Top
{
    public Middle Middle;
    public Fred[] Freds;
}

public static void Test()
{
    Top top = new Top();
    top.Middle.Freds = new Fred[2];
    top.Middle.Freds[0].Name = "Fred20";
    top.Middle.Freds[1].Name = "Fred21";

    top.Freds = new Fred[2];
    top.Freds[0].Name = "Fred10";
    top.Freds[1].Name = "Fred11";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(top.GetType());
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        x.Serialize(sw, top);
    }
    string xml = sb.ToString();

    string[] lines = xml.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("   " + line.Trim());
    }

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml));
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    object o = x.Deserialize(sr);
    Debug.WriteLine("Deserialized into " + o);
     Top go2 = (Top)o;

    if (go2.Freds == null)
        Debug.WriteLine("   go2.Freds is null");
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("   go2.Freds[0].Name is \"" + go2.Freds[0].Name + "\"");
    if (go2.Middle.Freds == null)
        Debug.WriteLine("   go2.Middle.Freds is null");
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("   go2.Middle.Freds[0].Name is \"" + go2.Middle.Freds[0].Name + "\"");

}
```

The XML looks good:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Top xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Middle>
     <Freds>
        <Fred>
           <Name>Fred20</Name>
        </Fred>
        <Fred>
           <Name>Fred21</Name>
        </Fred>
     </Freds>
  </Middle>
  <Freds>
     <Fred>
        <Name>Fred10</Name>
     </Fred>
     <Fred>
        <Name>Fred11</Name>
     </Fred>
  </Freds>
</Top>
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
Deserialized into Top
go2.Freds[0].Name is "Fred10"
go2.Middle.Freds is null
```

And xsd also gets it wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Top" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="Top" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="Middle">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Freds" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Fred" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Did you try to have the member name different than the element name? I.e. `public PLD[] PLDs;` for example.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't include it because it's huge, but since it is the problem object, you really should put in what the PLD object looks like

Comment: I've just tried this with a very simple example and it works as expected. Is there something wrong with the PLD class itself?

Comment: Possibly important note: I am using Compact Framework.  It looks like maybe this is one of the many strange things left out of CF?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes as a trick, what i'll do is use the visual studio command line tool 'xsd.exe' for something like this.  run

```
xsd.exe result.xml
```

on your xml file and get an xsd back.  Then run xsd again on the result .xsd file

```
xsd.exe result.xsd /c
```

and compare the class that you get back with the class you have.  that might answer your questions

Comment: Think this should be a comment... Since it does not provide a real solution to **this** problem.